# React: Updating / appending an array in state from a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a multi-step form with some caveats:

1. There's a number input field that dictates how many upcoming dropdowns are displayed (i.e., if I put in 3, there would be 3 dropdowns below it).
2. The dropdowns have a default value, randomized from a list - no dropdown can have the same value.
3. The dropdowns can be edited by the user, but will warn the user if another dropdown has the same value.

I chose dropdowns because the values that they pull from (a JSON) will not change, although I'm not entirely sure it's a good idea. I've been able to do step 1 and 2, but I'm stuck on step 3.

The problem I'm having is that I could not save the initial randomized values from `randomNpcList` the dropdown into `state` (although at least, they are displayed just fine), and changing the value of the dropdowns doesn't seem to save it into the array in `state` either (thus, my check code never really runs).

Here's my code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-rain-vbr1mi

Here's my code for the form:

```
export default class SeasonalDataForm extends Component {
    state = {
        step: 1,
        hasLoadedJson: false,
        duration: 4
        total_npcs: 5,
        selected_npcs: [],
    }

    containsObject(obj, list) {
        for (const element of list) {
            if (element === obj) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        /* Load data from JSON
        localStorage.setItem(`persistentJsonData`, JSON.stringify(jsonData));
        this.setState({ hasLoadedJson: true });*/
    }
    
    prevStep = () => { // go back to previous step }

    nextStep = () => { // proceed to the next step }

    handleChange = input => e => {
        switch (input) {
            case 'selected_npc':
                const jsonData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`persistentJsonData`));
                const npcFromDropdown = jsonData.NPCs.find((npc) => parseInt(npc.id) === parseInt(e.target.value));

                if (!this.containsObject(npcFromDropdown, this.state.selected_npcs)) {
                    this.setState({ selected_npcs: [...this.state.selected_npcs, npcFromDropdown] });
                } else { alert("NPC already selected.");}
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { step, hasLoadedJson } = this.state;
        const { duration, selected_region, total_npcs, selected_npcs, } = this.state;
        const values = { duration, selected_region, total_npcs, selected_npcs, };

        if (hasLoadedJson) {
            switch (step) {
                case 2:
                    return (
                        <NpcSelector nextStep={this.nextStep} prevStep={this.prevStep} handleChange={this.handleChange} values={values} defaults={MIN_MAX_DEFAULTS} />
                    );
                default:
            }
        } else {
            return (
                <div>Data loading...</div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code for the NPC selector:

```
const NpcSelector = ({ nextStep, prevStep, handleChange, values, defaults }) => {
    const jsonData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`persistentJsonData`));
    const weekStructure = jsonData.Season_Length.find((week) => parseInt(week.week_structure) === parseInt(values.duration));
    const totalNpcs = values.total_npcs;
    const npcList = jsonData.NPCs;
    let randomNpcList = [];

    let i = 0;
    while (i < totalNpcs) {
        let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * npcList.length);
        let npc = npcList[index];
        if (containsObject(npc, randomNpcList)) {
            continue;
        } else {
            i++;
            randomNpcList.push(npc);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>NPCs</h2>
            <form>
                <label>
                    Total NPCs:
                    <input type="number" name="npcs" min={defaults.NPCS.MIN} max={defaults.NPCS.MAX} defaultValue={weekStructure.npcs} onChange={handleChange('total_npcs')} />
                </label>
                Currently selected randomized NPCs:
                {
                    randomNpcList && randomNpcList.map((npc, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={`selected_npc_${index}`}>
                                <select name={`npc_selected_${index}`} value={npc.id} onChange={handleChange('selected_npc')} >
                                    {
                                        npcList && npcList.map((value, index) => {
                                            return (<option key={index} value={value.id}>{value.name}</option>);
                                        })
                                    }
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NpcSelector
```

And the JSON file would look something like this:

```
{
    "Season_Length": [{"week_structure": 4,"npcs": 5,}],
    "NPCs": [
        {"id": 1,"name": "Akara"},
        {"id": 2,"name": "Charsi"},
        {"id": 3,"name": "Deckard"},
        {"id": 4,"name": "Flavie"},
        {"id": 5,"name": "Gheed"},
        {"id": 6,"name": "Kashya"},
        {"id": 7,"name": "Warriv"}
    ],
}
```

Ideally, for example, if I put in the number of NPCs as 4, the system would create 4 dropdowns, each with a random, non-repeating NPC (ex: Akara, Charsi, Flavie, Kashya). This would be saved in the state, and checked against any changes (ex: changing Kashya into Warriv is okay, changing Kashya into Akara would trigger an alert).

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I tried to reproduce the issue, and actually missing out few dependencies. Could you please add codesandbox ?  helps us to debug.

Comment: @Anu, here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-rain-vbr1mi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some minimal changes in SeasonalDataForm and NPCSelector, please find the forked sandbox. Let me know if this is what you wanted, or do you expect something else.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-hodgkin-6gj86l?file=/src/SeasonalDataGenerator/SeasonalDataForm.js

Thanks,
Anu